# Convert an escaped backslash to be an escaping backslash

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string from the server that the backslash are escaped:

`const s = 'text\\n'`

Because the backslashes are escaped, the backslash that is supposed to escape the new line is ignored. So my string doesn't have a new line as it should.

I would like to have my variable s to contain: `text\n`

I test this using length property:

```
'text\\n'.length === 6;  // this is wrong
'text\n'.length === 5;   // this is correct
```

How do I convert the wrong string to be the correct string?

Comment: You might want to fix the server. Can you show us the code that is generating the `const s = 'text\\n'` bit? Newlines are probably not the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all escaped new lines with actual new lines.

```js
'text\\n'.replaceAll('\\n', '\n')
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.